# Table of Contents in a Constitution style document

Tags: table-of-contents

I am trying to get this output:
[image]

I am just putting the normal table of contents command

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\text{\ding{51}}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\text{\ding{55}}}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\makenomenclature

% Title page starts here%

\begin{document}
\title{\bfseries \Huge Constitution of IISER Mohali Quiz Club - "A Brighter Lamp" \\ \vspace{1.0cm}
\includegraphics[width=3.0cm]{IMQC_logo_5x5.png} }

\date{Assented to xxxxxxx 2016; Date of commencement xxxxxx 2016.}
\maketitle
%Title page ends here%

%Contents page starts here%

\tableofcontents
\tocloftpagestyle{fancy}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{\thepage}

%Contents Page ends here%

%Preamble%
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\chapter{Preamble}

\end{document}
```

and I get this
[image]

How do I do this?

Comment: Please post a compilable document, not just a single line of code

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: And now reduce it to the minimal compilable version, please